# how to make a mongoose query to search for matching arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I am making a chat app where the user when first time sends a message to a person a new conversation is created in the database, But before creating a new one every time, I want to check whether the conversation exists, I'am building this in Node.js and using express framework & I'am using Mongoose to handle the database

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Conversation = new mongoose.Schema({
    Users : [
        {
            user_id : {
                type : String,
                required : true
            },
            username : {
                type : String,
                required : true
            },
            name : {
                type : String,
                required : true
            },
            profileUrl : {
                type : String,
                required : true
            }
        }
    ],
    createdAt : {
        type : Date,
        default : Date.now,
        required : true
    }

});


module.exports = mongoose.model("Conversation",Conversation);
```

Is there a query where I can check if there is an conversation which matches with the array I'm passing, I couldn't find a way to search for array with objects and I want all the fields to be equal not just single one

Comment: Chat App in NodeJS? Are you using Socket.IO?

Comment: Yeah I'm using socket.io and rabbitmq

Answer (score 0):

//Create a callback function on
module.exports.FindMessage= function (conditionQuery, callback) {
    Users .find(conditionQuery, callback)
}

//than

User.FindMessage({$or:[{username:username}]},function(err,message){
            if(err) throw err
            if(message.length > 0 )
            {

```
        }
        else
        {
         }
```